# How to connect office 365 for C# synch

Tags: c#, azure, office365, exchangewebservices

I have a need to connect to Office 365 in order to get some scheduling appointment for a room, make a book on a room if is available, modify and detele room's booking.
Log time ago I used Exchange 2007/10 for synchronisation, but now I'm a little lose in the Office 365 environment ...

I try to use Microsfoft Graph API and my personnal (just a mail on outlook.live.com) or company Outlook account in order to play with the use case.

But I don't understand how to connect a C# program to the new Office 365 access, because I Exchange 07/10 it was with a IIS actived EWS service with a certification. Now It seem to be with a Azure ID, but I don't understand if is really reccured even if you only use a simple C# program with you personnal account, you don't have a Azure App IP ...

Someony can give me some clues to create my connection plz ?

Thank a lot

Answer (score 1):

> I try to use Microsfoft Graph API and my personnal (just a mail on outlook.live.com) or company Outlook account in order to play with the use case.

You can get a proper Office365 to learn with by joining the Office365 developer program which is free https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/dev-program. You will also get an Access to the Azure Portal with this and be able to create Application registrations for oAuth

I would also suggest you look at using the Graph explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer this allows you to test and learn how the Graph works

When you ready to code you can use the QuickStart for the Graph https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start which is quite good and step you through what you need to do.